# Does casting a char array to another type violate strict-aliasing rules?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

Consider these two functions:

```
int f1()
{
  alignas(int) char buf[sizeof(int)] = {};
  return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf);
}

int f2()
{
  alignas(int) char buf[sizeof(int)] = {};
  char* ptr = buf;
  return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr);
}
```

GCC warns that the first violates strict-aliasing rules.  But the second is OK.

Clang accepts both without complaint.

Is the warning legitimate?

Comment: Yes. The "object" here is either a `char` or the array of `char`s and the glvalue is of type `int`; nothing in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#8 covers this case.

Comment: @T.C. do you mean it's impossible by standard, to alias a region of char, as some other type T ? because that's how optional and variant works isn't it. I can't help but to find this idea, if true, a risk to a these practical needs. I thought the exceptions to aliasing were including char for that purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The warning is legitimate. `f2` is not OK (it is undefined behaviour), it just doesn't provoke the warning.

I suspect the reason that `f2` doesn't provoke the warning is that:

```
int f3()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i);
    return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr);
}
```

Is *entirely* legal. You can use a `char*` (or a `void*`) as a "universal pointer" - provided you cast back to the right type before access. GCC is clearly being careful to avoid warning about `f3`, at a cost of not warning about `f2`.

Clang is failing to warn about either `f1` or `f2` - but it is not required to.

Comment: Needs standard quotes.