# Type punning. What is allowed?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

I am sending udp packets across the network. The messages consist of a header and a part that can differ from message to message. The header contains a tag so that the receiver knows how to interpret the data. Ie something like this

```
struct Datagram {
    uint8_t message_type;
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t data[MAX_SIZE];
};
```

the receiver would do something like this

```
void readMessage(Datagram* data){
    uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)data;
    uint8_t type = *ptr;
    ptr++;
    uint8_t size = *ptr;
    ptr++;
    if (type == 0) { 
        uint16_t* x = (uint16_t*)ptr;
        //...
    } else if (type == 1) {
        //...
    }
```

I have done similar things before and never encountered a problem with such casts. However, now I read about type punning and from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) I understand that the only other types I would be allowed to cast a `Datagram*` to is `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte`. However, I would need it the other way around (ie receiving into a buffer `char[MAX_SIZE]` and then reinterpreting as something different, which isnt allowed).

Now I am a bit confused how I should interpret the raw `Datagram`. Am I missing something, or is there really no (safe) way to reinterpret an array of bytes as something different?
What is the common way to reinterpret a raw stream of bytes as a certain type?

PS: There are quite some q/a s on type punning on SO, but the ones I found mainly concentrate on C (even if tagged as C++).

Comment: The only standard way is to use std::memcpy.  Otherwise you need to check if your compiler supports the extensions you need to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does casting a char array to another type violate strict-aliasing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298619/does-casting-a-char-array-to-another-type-violate-strict-aliasing-rules)

Comment: @user694733 the question is related but not really a dupe, because it only asks for what is not allowed. I already know more or less what isnt allowed and why, but I want to know how to workaround this restrictions. Using memcpy could be an answer

Comment: There is no legal way. The C++ standard is broken in that respect - basically, the compiler optimizer guys made it illegal without a "way out". That's different in C because strict aliasing is "opt-in" in C, but always on in C++ with no "opt-out". In addition to that you're relying on alignment requirements, but those are implementation-defined.